# how to get UIButton color in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

i have UIButton with background colour, now i want that Button colour to be set in separate colour filed

i tried by this method :

initialising :

```
var color1 = UIColor()
color1 = dateBtn1.backgroundColor!
```

setting :

```
if color1 == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
                dateBtn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

            }else{
                dateBtn1.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 85/255, green: 175/255, blue: 101/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }
```

my crash Report :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -isEqual: not defined for the UIColor <UIPlaceholderColor: 0x7f953241d150>; need to first convert colorspace.'
```

Answer (score 3):

It will work. Your issue is with improper Unwrapping and accessing the default button.backgroundColor property.

[image: Success Case]

Failure Case:
[image]

Comment: then y its not accepting this condition if color1 == UIColor.lightGrayColor() {
                dateBtn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

            }else{
                dateBtn1.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 85/255, green: 175/255, blue: 101/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }

Comment: The color1 property is not set because your 'dateBtn1' backgroundColor is not set by default. You can compare both image mainly //Edwin comment.

Comment: no i have set button color programatically its work fine but while comparing i getting crash dude

Comment: can you show setting code of button color property?

Comment: Its not issue with UIcolor because you can simply check this line
"print (UIColor.lightGrayColor() == UIColor.blueColor())"